# Post an image along some form data Retrofit to WCF Rest

Tags: android, image, wcf, retrofit

This is my method that is used to send some form data, but i want to send an image also, is this possible using this same method and adding it using an image property in the class or it is more reasonable sending it using another method separatly.

```
@POST("PostBanderolDataJSON")
        Call<ReportPostData> PostData(@Body ReportPostData reportdata);
```

This is my class:

```
public class ReportPostData {

    private int Id;

    private String Banderolnr;

    private String Pharmacy;

    private String Place;

    private String LocationLongitude;

    private String LocationLatitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Multi Part

For example

```
@Multipart
        @POST("/v1/upload/sell-image")
        Call<CustomerUploadImageResponse> signUp(
                @Header(KEY_X_AUTH) String authToken,
                @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> signUpDataList
        );
```

To Generate signUpDataList Use like

```
List<MultipartBody.Part> signUpDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        signUpDataList.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("qid", "1333"));
        signUpDataList.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("ut", "xyz");
        String path = customerImageUploadData.getImageUrl();
        Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtil.getBitmap(mActivity, path);
        if (null != bitmap) {
            MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "img",
                    "profile.jpg",
                    RequestBody.create(null, ImageUtil.getBytesFromBitmapFullQuality(bitmap))
            );
            signUpDataList.add(part);
        }
```